# How do I select an object and a count together in Rails 3 Active Record Query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, active-relation

How do I do something like this in active query?

```
select product.*, count(product_id) AS product_counts
group by(product.*) 
order by product_counts;
```

I tried this in active query:

```
Product.select("product fields, count(product_id) AS product_counts").group("product fields").order(product_counts)
```

The resultset i get back contains only the products that are sorted in the correct count order, but no count value.  I did a .to_sql and it returns the correct sql.

How can I do this or something similar while being efficient on the db?

Another related question is, how do I do a `.select("product.*)` or `.group("product.*")` in active query?  Right now I have to list every field out, eg. `.group("product.id, product.name, product.price...etc")`

Answer (score 0):

@Kevin,

Actually you are getting back product_counts the only thing to be aware of is that virtual attributes will not be displayed in the console so if you have:

```
products = select product.*, count(product_id) AS product_counts
group by(product.*) 
order by product_counts;

#You can access the product_counts just as you would expect
products.first.product_counts
```

Question 2:
Not sure what you are trying to achieve with group("product.*"), if you want to get distinct rows you can use DISTINCT in your select e.g. Product.select("DISTINCT *")